# iText7 References old BouncyCastle Library

Tags: java, bouncycastle, itext7

Ok, I'm trying to execute a test Java program compiled against iText (7) and BouncyCastle (154) jar files. Everything works swimmingly until I try to add an OCSP response when calling the signDetached function.

My code is basically this piece of code from the iText website:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-3#855-c3_07_signwithocsp.java

With my certificate and password details replaced where necessary. It all compiles ok but when I run it, the Java code falls over with the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.bouncycastle.ocsp.RevokedStatus at
>   com.itextpdf.signatures.OcspClientBouncyCastle.getEncoded(OcspClientBouncyCastle.java:148)
>   at com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner.signDetached(PdfSigner.java:510)
>   at DECSignHello.DoSign(DECSignHello.java:314) at
>   DECSignHello.main(DECSignHello.java:125) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.ocsp.RevokedStatus
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:600) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:777) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:750) at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:326) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:731) ... 4 more

When I dig a little deeper I see that iText7 is using a java class called `OcspClientBouncyCastle` that references a class file from a much older BouncyCastle implementation (something prior to 151 - haven't identified exactly which version it is yet that contains this class). The class it's referencing is `org.bouncycastle.ocsp.RevokedStatus`. The code that's causing the problem is this:

`status instanceof org.bouncycastle.ocsp.RevokedStatus`

On line 148 of `OcspClientBouncyCastle.java`. It doesn't exist in any BouncyCastle jar file from 151 and above...

The same iText class `OcspClientBouncyCastle.java` file seems to also use the newer BouncyCastle classes found in the path `org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.*` for everything else BouncyCastle related so it appears as if it's using two different BouncyCastle implementations. At least that's what it looks like to me.

It's causing my OCSP testing to fall over because when I get an invalid OCSP response from my service provider (which expected because I'm using a revoked certificate to test with) the class referenced by the `OcspClientBouncyCastle.java` source code is not found in the classpath - so it all falls over with an untrappable error.

Now, I can get around this in a manner of speaking by doing manual OCSP verification using a valid class from the 154 BouncyCastle implementation as follows:

```
BasicOCSPResp l_resp = l_ocsp_client.getBasicOCSPResp(l_other_cert, l_root_cert, l_ocsp_url);
SingleResp[] l_response = l_resp.getResponses();
```

and so on...

However, as soon as I use the iText7 `PdfSigner.signDetached` function (passing and instance of `OcspClientBouncyCastle` for the OCSP client parameter) then the `OcspClientBouncyCastle.java` code is invoked and the 'old' class is used.

I suppose I could get around that error by including the older (yet to be identified) BouncyCastle jar files in my classpath but that seems like such a cluttered solution.

I could also edit the `OcspClientBouncyCastle.java` file and correct the errant function to use a newer implementation of the BouncyCastle functions but that seems like overkill too.

I should mention that I'm working in an AIX environment on the command line. So no Java development tools/environment - just `vi` and I'm building my classpath (at compile and run time) manually and executing my code using ksh shell scripts.

So, after all of that, I guess my question is this: Can anyone think of a reasonable reason why iText would implement the class `OcspClientBouncyCastle` this way?

I'm a long-time follower/user of this forum but this is my first time posting anything. I realise my 'question' is rather broad in scope so apologies upfront for that.

Herewith the sample code:

```
/*
 * This class is part of the white paper entitled
 * "Digital Signatures for PDF documents"
 * written by Bruno Lowagie
 * 
 * For more info, go to: http://itextpdf.com/learn
 */
package signatures.chapter3;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.DigestAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.CryptoStandard;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.OcspClient;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.OcspClientBouncyCastle;

public class C3_07_SignWithOCSP extends C3_01_SignWithCAcert {
    public static final String SRC = "src/main/resources/hello.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "results/chapter3/hello_cacert_ocsp.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, DocumentException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("c:/home/blowagie/key.properties"));
        String path = properties.getProperty("PRIVATE");
        char[] pass = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD").toCharArray();

        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", provider.getName());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), pass);
        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pass);
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        OcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
        C3_07_SignWithOCSP app = new C3_07_SignWithOCSP();
        app.sign(SRC, DEST, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Ghent", 
                null, ocspClient, null, 0);
    }

} 
C3_08_GetTsaUrl.java 
/*
 * This class is part of the white paper entitled
 * "Digital Signatures for PDF documents"
 * written by Bruno Lowagie
 * 
 * For more info, go to: http://itextpdf.com/learn
 */
package signatures.chapter3;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.CertificateUtil;

public class C3_08_GetTsaUrl {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("c:/home/blowagie/key.properties"));
        String path = properties.getProperty("PRIVATE");
        char[] pass = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD").toCharArray();

        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", provider.getName());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), pass);
        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);        
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[i];
            System.out.println(String.format("[%s] %s", i, cert.getSubjectDN()));
            System.out.println(CertificateUtil.getTSAURL(cert));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you copy-pasted your code. Links may get broken over time, and one of the points of SO is that your question and eventual answers may be useful for other people in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Noted. Code has been added to my post. Although, the problem isn't with this code, it's with a class library the code references in iText.

Comment: You didn't tag your question with `itext7`, which unfortunately meant that it didn't get noticed by anyone at iText Software, until now, just because by happenstance I searched for questions about iText. I'll share your question on the iText Slack.

Comment: iText7 is compiled with BounCycastle version 1.49 in mind :)